# $(nm)$th prime is less than the $m$th power of $n$th prime

Tags: number-theory, inequality

Let $n, m >1$. Prove that $P_{n\cdot m}<P_{n}^m$, where $P_{n\cdot m}$ is the $n\cdot m$th prime and $P_{n}^m$ is the nth prime of degree $m$.

Comment: Your approach so far?

Comment: So far I have no idea. This is the lemma that I need to prove to support my main theorem.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

There's always a prime between $n$ and $2\cdot n$.

Comment: How can I use it in proving $P_{n\cdot m}<P_{n}^m$?